# AngularJS double nested ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a double nested ng-repeat to cycle through objects in objects, and it just doesn't work. Can someone point me to the problem? It'd be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="diningHall in diningHalls | orderBy:menuSort">
  {{diningHall.id}}
  <li ng-repeat="item in diningHall.menu">
  {{item.name}}
  </li>
</li>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.diningHalls = [
        { 'id': 'PlaceA' ,
            'menu': [
          {'name':'Dungeness crab fritters with scallions, chervil, and celery root julienne'},
          {'name':'Grilled Llano Seco Ranch pork loin with roasted artichokes'},
          {'name':'Zuppa di frutta with clementine sherbet'},
          {'name':'Dill, radishes, and curly endive'},
          {'name':'Panna cotta with blood orange gelatin'}
                ]

        },
        { 'id': 'PlaceB',
            'menu': [
           {'name':'Bacon'},
           {'name':'More Bacon'},
           {'name':'Still Bacon'},
           {'name':'Delicious Bacon'},
           {'name':'Best Bacon'}
                ]
        }
  ];
```

Comment: What is menuSort in the orderBy clause?

Comment: It's just an option selected from a dropdown element; that shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what exactly is failing?  Is it the looping that is failing or the display? And to answer your question, it shouldn't matter - it was just something not explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is not Angular but the HTML Format there some missing `<ul>` elements in your lists. Try this in your HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="d in diningHalls | orderBy:menuSort">
       {{d.id}}
       <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="item in d.menu">
            {{item.name}}
         </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q69jR/2/)

Comment: Oh shoot, that did it! Why do we need the extra <ul> ?